# Waiting until document ready is complete to render page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of JS in my document ready function that hides / shows divs based on cookies. It has some weird shiftiness when loading that I dislike. Is there a way to supress page rendering which I load or something?

Thanks

Comment: You could consider hiding everything with `display: none` and only showing it when ready.  I would generally advise against this though.

Comment: does the term 'Flash of Unstyled Content' apply here?

Comment: @DanPichelman: Possibly, but if you were styling with JS you're doing something wrong

Comment: @bergi Agreed, but 'FOUC' isn't the sort of search term that would come naturally to mind.  It seems like a good description of the OP's issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .blockUI() plug in for that .It is a beautiful plugin .

[see here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)